# When is NavigationStart fired in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Is NavigationStart event fired on page load, after redirection has occurred from an external site to this site?

Sample code which is not fired on redirection from external site to SomeComponent.

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router'; 

export class SomeComponent { 
   constructor(public _router: Router, private _activeRoute: ActivatedRoute,    private _location: Location) {
     this.router = _router; 
     this.router.events
         .filter(e => e instanceof   NavigationStart)     
         .pairwise()
         .subscribe((e) => { alert(e); }); 
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Yes, it doesnt work. Wanted to confirm , since didnt find any documentation around this.

Comment: NavigationStart  was not fired in this case.

Comment: I what class? Would you mind providing some information?

Comment: import { Router, ActivatedRoute, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';
export class SomeComponent{
constructor(public _router: Router, private _activeRoute: ActivatedRoute, private _location: Location) {
        this.router = _router;

 this.router.events
            .filter(e => e instanceof NavigationStart)
            .pairwise().subscribe((e) => {
                alert(e);
            });
}
}

Comment: Please edit the question and add the code there. Code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: Just a hint: The line `this.router = _router;` is redundant. If you add `private`, `public`, or `protected` to a constructor parameter, this is implied (you would need to remove the `_` from the parameter name to get the exact same result).

Comment: What are you using `pairwise()` for? Have you tried without?

Comment: Agree with both the comments you shared and made changes, but the behavior is still the same.

Comment: There is an Azure AD authentication that takes place before redirection. (from external to SomeComponent) Could this be the reason by any chance.

Comment: How do your routes look like? Are you sure the router is working at all?

Comment: As per the route in App.Module, I dont have query string params added. But when the redirection occurs from external site, it passes querystring params. Basically there are multiple ways of landing on SomeComponent. If redirection happens from within my site, no params are passed.

Comment: How are query parameters related?

Comment: { path: 'some', component: SomeComponent }
and not 
 { path: 'some/:id', component: SomeComponent },

Comment: And `SomeComponent` is shown or do you get an error message in the browser console?

Comment: yes. It is displayed

Comment: Your constructor above should be in `AppComponent` not in `SomeComponent`, you can't expect to get notified about `NavigationStart` inside the component that is added during navigation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get notified about `NavigationStart` inside the component that is created and added during navigation. 
Instead add the code to `AppComponent`

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router'; 

export class AppComponent { 
   constructor(public _router: Router, private _activeRoute: ActivatedRoute,    private _location: Location) {
     this.router = _router; 
     this.router.events
         .filter(e => e instanceof   NavigationStart)     
         .pairwise()
         .subscribe((e) => { alert(e); }); 
   }
}
```

Comment: i tried adding this in the App.Module.ts but the application hangs. I tried debugging, it hits the ctor, but after that no response.

Comment: and no error in the browser console? Can you try to reproduce in a Plunker? Plunker provides a ready-to-use Angular2 template

Comment: Ok, I rebooted the machine, and it seems to hit the ctor. But the event was not fired. I tried putting the event in  ngOnInit() also, but the event didnt fire.

Comment: Sorry, can't tell from this information. Please try creating a Plunket.

Comment: Thanks so much for all your help..greatly appreciate it.. will try that and let you know..I have another question on stackoverflow I am trying to resolve , if you have any suggestions I could try , it would help greatly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42497650/document-referrer-is-always-blank-in-angular-2/42505223#42505223
I tried using NavigationStart here as well. Also tried LocationStrategy. But not able to get this working.

Comment: I saw the question, but I don't know

Comment: I guess with pairwise, it starts emitting events on the 2nd navigation.

Answer (score 0):

I used the code below for angular 8

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private router:Router) { 
    this.router.events.subscribe((e) => { if(e instanceof NavigationStart) { console.log(e); } });
  }
}
```