# $locationChangeStart equivalent in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular4-router

What is the $locationChangeStart equivalent in Angular 4? I am looking for a handler to track the url changes. I read that there is a [location service](https://angular.io/api/common/Location) but I am not sure if I need to use this or look for something here https://angular.io/guide/router.. Any pointers would be really helpful. Thanks!

Update: I want to do this inside a service not a component.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Angular there are router events that you can subscribe to:

What you want is the `NavigationStart` event.

[Angular Docs NavigationStart](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationStart)

Here is a nice code example provided as an answer on [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42501637/when-is-navigationstart-fired-in-angular-2) on how to use it properly.

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router'; 

export class AppComponent { 
   constructor(public _router: Router, private _activeRoute: ActivatedRoute,    private _location: Location) {
     this.router = _router; 
     this.router.events
         .filter(e => e instanceof   NavigationStart)     
         .pairwise()
         .subscribe((e) => { alert(e); }); 
   }
}
```

Comment: can I use it inside a service?

Comment: Yes, you can use it in a service. However it is already provided as a service that exposes an observable so it may be a bit redundant to do so if you're intention is to than provide your 'wrapper' service.